# Why codeigniter not showing the variable sent from controller to view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send a variable '`$msg_notf`' from my controller to my view but every time I do this, codeigniter returns the error "Undefined variable: msg_notf" .

My Controller,

```
public function send_message(){
  $this->load->model('model_student');
  $msg_send=$this->model_student->send_message($this->session->userdata('roll_no'));
  if($msg_send==true){
    $result['msg_notf']='message sent';
   $this->load->helper('url');
   redirect('http://localhost/CheckIn_System/index.php/student',$result);

}else{
    $result['msg_notf']='unable to send message';
 $this->load->helper('url');
redirect('http://localhost/CheckIn_System/index.php/student',$result);
}
}
```

In view,

```
echo $msg_notf;
```

Comment: You do a redirect, so the current process's variables aren't doing to exist in the next request unless you pass them in e.g. a session variable.

Comment: yup I should have used $this->load->view('view',$result) instead of redirect. Thanks

Comment: you can only pass array when you are loading a view you can't use this  redirect('http://localhost/CheckIn_System/index.php/student',$result);
 and get echoed the variable ethier you need to put $result in session or you need to append it to url to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
public function  __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');//load once Controller load
}

public function send_message()
{
    $this->load->model('model_student');
    $msg_send=$this->model_student->send_message($this->session->userdata('roll_no'));
    if($msg_send==true){
        $result['msg_notf']='message sent';
        $this->load->view('student',$result);//passing data to view

    }else{
        $result['msg_notf']='unable to send message';

        $this->load->view('student',$result);//passing data to view
    }
}
```

in view

```
foreach ($msg_notf  as $new_msg_notf)
{
echo $new_msg_notf['your_data_field'];//showing your data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller may look like this :

```
    public function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
      }

    public function send_message(){
      $this->load->model('model_student');

      $msg_send=$this->model_student->send_message($this->session->userdata('roll_no'));

      if($msg_send==true){

        $result['msg_notf']='message sent';

       $this->load->view('path', $result); // path of the
       http://localhost/CheckIn_System/index.php/student

     }else{
        $result['msg_notf']='unable to send message';
        $this->load->view('path',$result);
    }
  }
```

Comment: then echo $msg_notf ; in the view

Answer (score 0):

If you want use redirect, the best idea is use Flashdata. Is a one-time session var that persists until you use it, then is deleted.

you need call: `$this->load->library('session');`

Declaration:
`$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');`

To read:
`$this->session->flashdata('item');`

Comment: his problem with passing data to view.

Comment: once page reload data will be lost with `flashdata`.

Answer (score 0):

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

The redirect() function does a "header redirect" to the URI specified. The optional second parameter allows you to choose between the "location" method (default) or the "refresh" method.

If you want to pass data into a view use

```
$this->load->view("View_file", $result);
```

and on the view page access it like

```
echo $msg_notf;
```

With redirect function you should use Session (Userdata or Flashdata)
Flashdata is preferred in this case.